# Tk combobox update box with new list

Tags: combobox, tk-toolkit

I have two comboboxes. If the user picks one entry from the first one, the second one should update so that the user only can pick certain things.

I populate the first box:

```
ttk::combobox  .dsm.nb.f1.entr_Box1     -textvariable GUI_BoxOne -values [list {first entr} {second entr}] -state readonly
```

Then I use bind to catch any changes:

```
bind  .dsm.nb.f1.entr_Box1 <<ComboboxSelected>> { ::UpdateCombobox }
```

If anything changes I repopulate the second box:

```
proc ::UpdateCombobox { } {

switch $::GUI_BoxOne {

  {first entr} {
     set ::GUI_BoxTwo {one new value}
  }

  {second entr} {
     set ::GUI_BoxTwo [list {first new value} {second new value} ]
  }
 }
}
```

This works fine for the first case of the switch, I get one entry in box two I can select, but I do not manage to populate the box by several new values (lines). "first new value" and "second new value" end up as one entry in the box. Logical somehow, it's one list, but how can i update all the values of a combobox at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.dsm.nb.f1.entr_Box2 configure -values`:

```
proc ::UpdateCombobox {} {
    .dsm.nb.f1.entr_Box2 configure -values [dict get {
        {first entr} {
           {one new value}
        }
        {second entr} {
            {first new value}
            {second new value}
        }
     } $::GUI_BoxOne]
}
```

Of course you can also use switch, but I usually prefer dicts for that.

The `-textvariable` just contains the current value, if you set it the current value is set.